# How to make rounded corners in image that was drawn with BezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uibezierpath

I have a tableView cell, that has an image view.
For this view I created UIImage extension, where I am drawing with bezierPath 2 rectangle, and then, from this drawing I make an image.

```
 class func drawTwoRectangles(_ frameOne: CGRect, frameTwo: CGRect, frameColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: frameOne.size.width, height: frameOne.size.height))
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 153/255.0, blue: 216/255.0, alpha: 1.0).setFill()

    let bpath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:1, y:1), size: CGSize(width: frameOne.size.width - 2, height: frameOne.size.height - 2)), byRoundingCorners: [.allCorners], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
    bpath.lineCapStyle = .round
    bpath.lineJoinStyle = .round

    bpath.close()
    bpath.fill()


    UIColor.white.setFill()
    UIColor.white.setStroke()

    let bpathTwo:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: frameTwo)
    bpathTwo.close()
    bpathTwo.fill()
    bpathTwo.stroke()

    frameColor.setStroke()

    let bpathThree:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:1, y:1), size: CGSize(width: frameOne.size.width - 2, height: frameOne.size.height - 2)), cornerRadius: 5)
    bpathThree.lineWidth = 2
    bpathThree.close()

    bpathThree.stroke()

    bpath.append(bpathTwo)
    bpath.append(bpathThree)

    context?.addPath(bpath.cgPath)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image!
}
```

So when I set this image into an Image view, corners are not smooth, they are blurred:[image]

Could you please advice, how to deal with it? 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: frameOne.size.width, height: frameOne.size.height))
```

with this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frameOne.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
```

By the way, you can pass `0.0` as third parameter, according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1623912-uigraphicsbeginimagecontextwitho?language=objc):

> The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

Comment: I usually use 0 for the scale, since the system figures out the scale of the device screen in that case.